# strcmp - expected primary-expression before ‘[’ token

Tags: c++, string, char, comparison

In my main code i have a operation where i want to to compare a certain character of a string "word[i]" with a latin letter "b". Obviously i tried to use " word[i] == "b" " but got an error. After a bit of research i found out that in C++ " word[i] == "b" " compares two pointers. It was suggested that one should use strcmp() instead.

So i used strcmp() but still got an error. Can someone explain to me why it is not working?

Minimal working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string test;
    cin >> test;
    if(strcmp(string[0], "a") == 0){
        cout << "yes";
    }
}
```

-->

```
untitled.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
untitled.cpp:8:18: error: expected primary-expression before ‘[’ token
    8 |  if(strcmp(string[0], "a") == 0){
      |                  ^
Compilation failed.
```

Comment: Please do not modify the question to apply the fixes provided in the answer. Doing so changes the context in which those answers were written and invalidates them. If you have additional information, add it at the bottom of to the question instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Obviously i tried to use " word[i] == "b" " but got an error

The expression `word[i]` (according to the presented program it seems you mean `test[i] == "b"`or more precisely `test[0] == "a"`) has the type `char` while the string literal `"b"` has the type `const char *`. So the compiler issues an error because the types are incompatible.

The function `strcmp` is designed to compare two c-strings. If you will write for example

```
strcmp( word[i], "b" ) == 0
```

then again you will get an array because the expression `word]i]` is not a pointer to a string. It yields a single character.

Moreover in this if statement

```
if(strcmp(string[0], "a") == 0){
```

you are using the type specifier `std::string` instead of an object.

What you need is just to write

```
if ( test[0] == 'a' ){
```

that is there are compared two objects of the type `char`: the object `test[0]` and the character literal `'0'`.

Answer (score 1):

**Your string is not called `string`; it is called `test`.**

You confused the compiler by giving a type name, instead of an expression.

Fix:

```
if(strcmp(test[0], "a") == 0){
//        ^^^^
```

---

However, this is still wrong. **`test[0]` is not a string; it is a single character.**

Solution:

```
if (test[0] == 'a') {
//             ^ ^
```

---

> After a bit of research i found out that in C++ " word[i] == "b" " compares to pointers

For C-strings, sure, but in C++ a `std::string` has `==` defined as you would expect.

Answer (score -1):

`string[0]` is invalid because `string` is a type name. It seems you mean `test[0]`.

Also note that `strcmp(test[0], "a") == 0` won't work because `test[0]` is `char` and `strcmp()` requires pointers to C-style strings (character sequences that ends with `'\0'`) as both arguments.

You want to compare characters, not strings, so it should be `test[0] == 'a'` or `test[0] == "a"[0]`.

Comment: Your proposed solution only works when `i` is `0`, and it also assumes null-termination with no embedded nulls. The first is antithetical to the stated question, and the latter was not specified in the question.

Comment: _"i want to to compare a certain character of a string "word[i]" with a latin letter "b"."_ The `0` in the code was just an example.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings terminating null character is included in array returned from [`c_str()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/)

Comment: Doesn't matter: it'll be in the wrong place if the input string has embedded nulls, which is supported by `std::string`. Don't use C library functions for C++ things.

Comment: And you're still assuming `i` is `0`